# CheckJNI Option is not Working

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-2.2-froyo

I have a rooted device and set the build properties as given in the Android Dev Link
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1
$ adb shell start
```

But after doing this i am getting CheckJNI is OFF in the DDMS log

Could any one has some solutions to turn the CheckJNI "on"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to data > localproperties
2. In localproperties if have write permission
3. Have a file with local.prop in your local disk with this text dalvik.vm.checkjni=true.
4. adb push /data/local.prop /local.prop.
5. Then restart the device then you will see CheckJNI Option in LOGCAT.